# Hard disk cloning tool on Tru64 unix

Tags: bootable-media

I have hp compaq ds15 server running Tru64 unix 5.1B with two scsi hard disks,
I want to get a tool that clones the entire hard disk to another new one.

Does anyone tried it before???

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://superuser.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)
Software recommendations are off-topic, but you could try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use 'dd' the standard UNIX copy utility....
or
Disklabel the new disk, make the filesystem(s), and then use vdump and vrestore to copy the filesystem(s) from the old to the new.

If you are using LSM to manage the old disk(s), you ~may~ be able to add the new disk as a volume mirror, let it sync, then 'snap' it off, then re-mount it as a new/copy of the old.  But that is fairly complex.

JPM

Comment: I have tried dd command but under gparted tool because i can't connect external media with my server to clone on but the command didn't run , It returns an error that it can't open the hard drive of unix system